# When i'm creating a react project in the terminal of vscode the following code pops up, what do I do to solve this? It seems foreign to me

Tags: reactjs, terminal

npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!

Answer (score 0):

Following commands works for me:

```
npm cache clean --force

npm audit fix --force
```